# Web2py sessions table does not exist?

Tags: mysql, web2py

Recently after some updates to some of my models, I got this error in web2py.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/acbart/web2py/gluon/main.py", line 457, in wsgibase
    session._try_store_in_db(request, response)
  File "/Users/acbart/web2py/gluon/globals.py", line 1116, in _try_store_in_db
    record_id = table.insert(**dd)
  File "/Users/acbart/web2py/gluon/dal.py", line 9114, in insert
    ret =  self._db._adapter.insert(self, self._listify(fields))
  File "/Users/acbart/web2py/gluon/dal.py", line 1360, in insert
    raise e
ProgrammingError: (1146, u"Table 'runestone_dev.web2py_session_runestone' doesn't exist")
```

My web2py application is named `runestone`, and the database is named `runestone_dev`. I've checked the MySQL database and the table doesn't exist. But it is my understanding that this is a table that should be automatically generated for me. Anyone know what gives? It doesn't appear to be an obvious problem with my code...

Comment: Do you have migrations disabled?

Comment: I have some of my individual tables migration's disabled, but overall

    settings.migrate = True

Comment: What is settings.migrate?

Comment: Apparently a useless variable added by the original creator, Sorry. I've tried setting the migrate_enabled=False parameter in the DAL definition, but it doesn't seem to affect things. What do you recommend I do about migrations? You think they might be interfering somehow?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like at some point web2py created the sessions table (and therefore the associated migrations meta-data file in the application's /databases folder), but subsequent to that, you either created/switched to a new database or dropped the table from the database. As a result, web2py thinks the table is in the database and is not attempting to re-create it.

In the application's /databases folder, look for a file with a name that matches the pattern *_web2py_session_runestone.table and delete it. This will prompt web2py to re-create the table in the database on the next request.

Comment: I haven't switched to a new database, and I don't recall dropping the table; although since the table is not in the database, you must surely be correct that it was somehow removed. However, there is no such file in my databases/ folder. All the other tables are there.

Comment: In your DAL connection, make sure you do **not** have `DAL(..., migrate_enabled=False)`, and when you connect the session, make sure you do **not** have `session.connect(..., migrate=False)`. On the next request, web2py should create the session table automatically. If not, I suggest you post on the Google Group for more troubleshooting.

Comment: I've tried without both parameters, and nothing changes. Thank you for time, though.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same error, and in my case I have solved it by doing next steps:

- reinstall web2py
- clone `runestone` project into application folder.
- create `web2py/applications/runestone/models/1.py` with `settings.database_uri = <your_connection_string>`. Connection string should looks like `postgres://username:passwd@localhost/dbname` if you are using Postgres.
- clone desired book into `web2py/applications/runestone/books/`
- edit book's `pavement.py` file: `'dburl': 'postgresql://bmiller@localhost/runestone',`. `dburl` should points to your database